# Interest: passing one test case but not a second?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class creditCard:
    def __init__(self,limit, apr, balance):
        self.limit = limit
        self.apr = apr
        self.balance = balance
        self.charges = {}
        self.payments = {}

    def charge(self, amount, day):
        if amount > self.limit - self.balance:
            return False

        self.charges[day] = amount
        self.balance += amount

    def payment(self, amount, day):
        if amount > self.limit - self.balance:
            return False

        self.payments[day] = amount
        self.balance -= amount

    def interest(self, balance):
        return (balance * self.apr) / 365

    def days_balance(self, balance_day):
        balance_to_date = 0
        months_interest = 0
        for day in range(1, balance_day+1):
            balance_to_date += self.charges.get(day, 0)
            balance_to_date -= self.payments.get(day, 0)
            months_interest += self.interest(balance_to_date)

            if day % 30 == 0:
                balance_to_date += months_interest
                months_interest = 0

        return round(balance_to_date, 2)
```

I have this program I wrote for an assignment in which the directions are extremely confusing ( I will post them below ) but I was given two test cases and I pass my first test case, but my second test case I must be making a mathematical or logical error? the function`days_balance()` should return 411.99 but returns 411.89 I use the same functions to calculate interest for my first test case so I am not understanding why it is not working properly for my second test case. any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Directions:

Given a Credit Card:

- each card has an  APR and Limit
- Interest is calculated daily at the close of each day but not applied. (my first issue)
- Interest is applied to the balance at the close of each 30-day period (opening day excluded)
- Asking for the balance on days 28/29 will give the same results but asking for the balance on day 30 will give you balance + all interest accrued.

Software should:

- Create an Account (opening a new card)
- Keep track of charges
- Keep track of payments
- Provide the outstanding balance for any given day (10 days after account opening)

Test cases:

- Customer opens a credit card with a 1k limit, at 35% APR
- Customer charges $500 on opening day
- Does not make anymore charges
- Day 30 he owes $514.38

Test case 2:

- customer opens a credit card with 1k limit and 35% APR
- customer charges $500 on opening day
- 15 days after opening he pays $200 (balance now 300)
- 25 days after opening he charges another $100 (balance now 400)
- total balance at the end of the month is 411.99

Here is how I am calling each method (my testing)

Test 1:

```
customer1 = creditCard(1000, 0.35, 0)
customer1.charge(500, 1)
print(customer1.days_balance(30))
```

Test 2:

```
customer2 = creditCard(1000, 0.35, 0)
customer2.charge(500, 1)
customer2.payment(200, 15)
customer2.charge(100, 25)
print(customer2.days_balance(30))
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for the test case 2?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The code I posted above should work for both test cases. When I run the code above I get $514.38 for the first test case but on the second test case, I get $411.89 instead of $411.99 I think I may be losing track of a day somewhere in my code. I can place my actual calls to the functions if you think that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the expected balance after 30 days like this:

```
((500 * 0.35) / 365) * 15 + ((300 * 0.35) / 365) * 10 + ((400 * 0.35) / 365) * 5 ~= 411.99
```

Your code calculates the balance like this:

```
((500 * 0.35) / 365) * 14 + ((300 * 0.35) / 365) * 10 + ((400 * 0.35) / 365) * 6 ~= 411.89
```

<strike>This looks like a classic 1-off error.</strike> I would recommend sticking strictly to 0-indexed code to avoid these.

You could insert a print call into your method to see how the `months_interest` evolves:

```
def days_balance(self, balance_day):
    balance_to_date = 0
    months_interest = 0
    for day in range(1, balance_day+1):
        balance_to_date += self.charges.get(day, 0)
        balance_to_date -= self.payments.get(day, 0)
        months_interest += self.interest(balance_to_date)

        if day % 30 == 0:
            balance_to_date += months_interest
            months_interest = 0

        print(day, months_interest, balance_to_date)

    return round(balance_to_date, 2)
```

Thinking about it a bit more, I think your code does what it's supposed to be, but the logic of the test case is off. If the customer charges 100 moneys on day 25 and interest is paid out on day 30, indeed the account will be at +400 for 6 days.

Comment: Oh, I see that makes complete sense. I do have a question about the error. Now if I changed my loop to use 0 indexing, wouldn't that throw off the user input? so when they put in day 15 it would really be 14? Thank you!

Comment: Yes thats true, somewhere you will have to convert from 1-based input to 0-based internals. I also tried to convert and have come to believe that the 1-based loop is actually fine in your case.

Comment: strange, so how would I go about reaching the test case? Is it the actual question or the way I am testing my code?

Comment: I find it difficult to wrap my head around the logic of the test case. Lets say the customer deposits $500 on day 1 he will get interest for that up until day 14. Because the customer makes a payment on day 15, the balance will already be lower and for day 15 he will get the lower interest. To get 15 days of the higher interest the customer would need to make the payment on day 16.

Comment: I have asked a couple of my friends who are more experienced than me and they have all said the same thing. That the question is worded terribly.

Comment: Haha well that happens... Maybe get some clarification from your instructor. Another point is that you don't account for the initial balance (so if the customer opens the credit card with $500 initially, he would not get any interest with your implementation)

Comment: Any advice for being able to handle the inital interest?

Comment: You could track the initial charge as a ... charge: `self.charge = {1: balance}` in `__init__`. (Edit: sorry got confused with the language)